# Hangout/WhatsApp/Slack in notifications

Tags: wingpanel, notifications

On Mac, when I recive a message in Google Hangout, WhatsApp or Slack, an notify pop is shown, is this also possible in elementary?

Comment: I'm running the Chrome webapp of hangouts and I get notifications. Though they are not integrated elementary notifications but show similar to native notifications. As far as the others, I don't have whatsapp and I have yet to receive a Slack notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slack has a native Linux app and is using notifications that are implemented by the OS. So, on eOS notifications from slack are just like other eOS notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Slack notifications can be enabled in the app.

[image]